# How to Connect Downstream Device to Azure IoT Central using x509 Certificates?

Tags: azure-iot-central

I am having trouble figuring out how to connect a downstream device to my IoT Central application. There is sample code showing how to do it using symmetric keys, but I am interested in using x509 certificate (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-central/core/how-to-connect-iot-edge-transparent-gateway#provision-a-downstream-device). I've tried using the code in the [EdgeX509AuthDownstreamDevice sample](https://github.com/Azure/iotedge/tree/master/samples/dotnet/EdgeX509AuthDownstreamDevice), but I am not sure what to put for the IOTHUB_HOSTNAME environment variable since IoT Central doesn't expose the IoT Hub. Has anyone gotten this to work?

Answer (score 0):

The variables used are misleading. You don't see the IoTHUB connection string.  Below, just replace the device shared key and it should work:

```
export IOTHUB_DEVICE_CONNECTION_STRING="HostName=edgegateway;DeviceId=thermostat1;SharedAccessKey={your device shared key}"
```

Comment: I'm using x509 certificates instead of symmetric keys so what would I put for the connection string in that case?